# Verify if two integer arrays have the same length in C programming?

Tags: c, arrays

This is what i have so far which does not work

```
int password [4] ;

int temp [4] ;

printf("Enter password : ") ;

Scanf ("%d" , &temp) ;


if (password.lenght == temp.lenght ) {

printf("The password is correct") ;

}

else {

printf ("Try Again");

}
```

Comment: password and temp are arrays, not structs, so they have no members and so password.* is illegal

Comment: Where are you taking input for `password`?

Comment: I suspect a [good book on C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will serve your future better than trying to learn by trial and error on Stack Overflow.

Comment: the password is ok, if the length is the same as the one stored ??

Comment: Password could be any four digit number

Answer (score 1):

Try using strings instead.

```
char password[4] = "abc";
char temp[4];

scanf("%s", temp);
```

Now, this will give you the string length:

```
size_t temp_len = strlen(temp);
```

Comment: Also better advise the safe way of scanning in a "string":`scanf("%3s", temp);`

Comment: @alk to be nitpicky to nitppicky, should be `scanf("%3s", temp);`

Comment: Ha, beat you be 3 secs @SouravGhosh :-P

Comment: How can you initialize char at password[4] as a string?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that what you are trying to do is to compare if given number is the one stored in password. You don't need an array for storing a number. You would need one if your password would have been a string.

To check if two numbers `a`, `b` have the same number of digits simply divide both of them by 10 in loop and check if they hit 0 in the same moment.

Comment: Alternatively, this will tell you if they have unequal digits: `(a / b >= 10) || (b / a >= 10)`

Comment: No i am trying to check if the two arrays have the same length , It is for an ATM program  I have to verify if the pin entered is a four digit number

Comment: If it is as you wrote in this comment, you aren't comparing arrays - just numbers. You might got confused because of String representation as `char[]`. Three digit number as well as four digit number will be stored in a variable which type is `int`.

Comment: For checking if a number is 4 digit just compare if it's greater then 999 and smaller than 10000.

Comment: so i am using two variables for the whole password verification loop first one is  password second one is tempPassword , what should the password be set to for this to work . Or should i only use one variable ?

Comment: int password = 1234; in this case, 1234 would be acceptable PIN.
int temp;
printf("Enter password : ") ;
Scanf ("%d" , &temp) ;
if (password == temp) {
//ok } else {wrong pin}

Comment: It works if it's greater than 999 and smaller than 10000 as long as the first digit is not 0 , is there anyway to fix this loop condition so that the first digit of the pin could also be 0

Comment: Add leading 1 to both numbers

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments to other answers, you want to check that someone has entered a four-digit string.  The easy way to do this is to use an array of `char` to store the input, and to use `strlen` to get the length of the input string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
...
char input[5];  // extra space for string terminator
printf( "Enter password: " );
if ( scanf( "%4s", input ) != 1 ) // read no more than four characters
{
  // error on input
}
else if ( strlen( input ) < 4 )
{
  // password too short
}
else
{
  // check password value
}
```

Comment: how do i verify that the pin number that is entered is an integer

Comment: Why is array size 5 ?

Comment: @Dstk_1998: C-"strings" always carry a trailing character, the so called `0`-terminator to mark the end of the "string". It they don't they aren't "strings", but just ordinary `char`-arrays.

Comment: @Dstk_1998 "*how do i verify that the pin number that is entered is an integer[?]*" That's another question.